# FPS starts out good but drops to terrible over time?

Tags: graphics-card

I'm playing on a Dell Studio 1558 with the following specification:

- core i5 M520 @ 2.4 GHz
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470
- 4 GB of RAM
- Windows 7

For some games sooner than others, but for most games I play (Arma 2, Tribes Ascend, Battlefield BC2) FPS starts out playable at 20-30 but then starts dropping over time to an unplayable level (10-15). For Arma 2 it can take like an hour but for Tribes (and presumably other UE games) it only takes a few minutes.

I'm suspecting it's the crappy ancient Dell supplied ATI display drivers having problems with keeping the right stuff in video memory or something like that. Since the FPS starts out fine I'm hopeful this is actually fixable by getting my drivers set right, question is how?

Are there ATI mobility drivers out there that are actually up to date and usable on this Dell?

Has anyone ever experienced or read about similar issues? Any sites or forums on laptop gaming advice you can recommend? I'm finding it hard to come up with good results on google and elsewhere.

Comment: try monitoring your heat as you play, is your computer overheating?  I like to use CUPID's hwmonitor for that: http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

Comment: In my experience, *"starts out good but gets worse over time"* is pretty much **always** due to overheating.

Comment: hwmonitor does say the max temp it has hit once it's going slow is 99 degrees C. I think that could also be the point it starts throttling? 

I didnt get the impression that the laptop was getting that warm but I guess it could be very local to the GPU. I should give the vents a cleaning.

Comment: Heat issues are likely.  You might try propping the back of the laptop up a bit, making sure not to block any of the vents.  Also, maybe getting a small fan would encourage airflow.  As far as drivers are concerned, I *think* you can use generic ATI drivers from the ATI website, but some laptops don't allow this (my toshiba doesn't, sadly :( ) so I used this guide: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t2_thUnvJv4

Comment: Most likely.  My old Geforce 8800GT would start throttling at 110C.  Try elevating the laptop off your desk/table and adding some airflow.  Throw a regular box fan at it, and see if the problem persists.

Comment: 99 C is quite high, yea at that point your CPU will probably naturally throttle back to prevent damage.  Try cleaning out your fan and air intake area.  Ideally you want to be no higher than 75C at full load.

Comment: Don't Intel chips have the feature of slowing themselves down when they're overheating?  Just so they don't turn themselves into slag?

Comment: @fbueckert yes, and this usually happens at around the 100C range

Comment: Then we have our answer, I believe.

Comment: @yx: Normal throttling temperature for a CPU is around 70-80°C.  It's GPUs that throttle around 80-100°C.

Comment: @BlueRaja are you sure about that for laptops?  I've had one with a bad fan and it didn't throttle till about 100C for me.  70C for a laptop cpu is fairly common due to crappy heat ventilation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out updating drivers can also help with heat issues.

I thought that you could only get ATI laptop drivers through your laptop maker, but apparently there is an [ati mobility compatibility tool](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonmob_win7-64.aspx) that can figure out if your laptop can work with the up to date generic ATI mobility drivers.

Now I'm getting a steady 92 degrees C on the Furmark burn in test (seems like a good tool for this, it graphs your temperature and maxes out your GPU) and no apparent throttling in games. Thank you for the comments on checking the temperature, it did not occur to me that that could cause throttling.